# Select lowest value and return first row only

Tags: sql, oracle

I am having difficulty returning the first row only from the following query. I am trying to return the lowest value in the RESULT column for a particular EVENT which works fine but it also returns other rows, I just want the one. What is the best way to achieve this?

```
SELECT E.EVENT_ID, E.EVENT_TYPE, E.EVENT_NAME, M.MEMBER_ID, M.MEMBER_FIRSTNAME, M.MEMBER_LASTNAME, (SELECT MIN(RESULT)
FROM RANK)
FROM EVENT E JOIN
RANK R
ON E.EVENT_ID = R.EVENT_ID JOIN
MEMBER M
ON M.MEMBER_ID = R.MEMBER_ID 
WHERE E.EVENT_ID = 'EVENT001'
ORDER BY RESULT;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The subquery in the solution below is copied and pasted from your original post, I didn't test it (obviously since I didn't have your tables), EXCEPT for the extra field: ROW_NUMBER() OVER ....  instead of the MIN(RESULT...)

This assigns a row in each "partition" using the ordering indicated (notice DESC), and in the outer query you select the rows where this row_number equals 1.

```
SELECT EVENT_ID, EVENT_TYPE, EVENT_NAME, MEMBER_ID, 
       MEMBER_FIRSTNAME, MEMBER_LASTNAME, RESULT
FROM
(
    SELECT E.EVENT_ID, E.EVENT_TYPE, E.EVENT_NAME,
           M.MEMBER_ID, M.MEMBER_FIRSTNAME, M.MEMBER_LASTNAME,
           R.RESULT,
           row_number() over (partition by e.event_id order by r.result) as rn
    FROM   EVENT E JOIN
           RANK R
           ON E.EVENT_ID = R.EVENT_ID JOIN
           MEMBER M
           ON M.MEMBER_ID = R.MEMBER_ID 
    WHERE  E.EVENT_ID = 'EVENT001'
)
WHERE RN = 1;
```

This assumes you want to return only one row, even if there is a tie for the lowest score. If there are ties, which row will be selected is undetermined (at least with this solution; you could add more clauses in ORDER BY). If in the case of ties you want ALL tied members to be listed, then you can use `DENSE_RANK()` instead of `ROW_NUMBER()`.

Comment: This returns invalid table name. I can't see why?

Comment: Does it tell you which table name is invalid? My front-end, whether I use SLQ*Plus, SQL Developer, or Toad, always does.

Comment: I am using oracle application express, it does not unfortunately.

Comment: Oh, of course, that explains it. I'll fix that and also what Matt pointed out.

Comment: Thanks, this is working. I am having trouble adding the result column after the member name? As currently only the event and member details are shown and I'd like to show the score as well.

Comment: I edited my post: I turned that bracket around, but I also added R.RESULT to the inner SELECT. See it?

Comment: I needed to put RESULT on the outer SELECT as well, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

So along with the row's `result` you want to show the event's minimum `result`. Use `MIN OVER` for this:

```
select 
  e.event_id, 
  e.event_type, 
  e.event_name, 
  m.member_id, 
  m.member_firstname, 
  m.member_lastname, 
  r.result, 
  min(r.result) over () as min_result
from event e 
join rank r on e.event_id = r.event_id 
join member m on m.member_id = r.member_id 
where e.event_id = 'EVENT001'
order by r.result;
```

Comment: Sorry, I just wanted to show the minimum result, not both. I have edited this part out.

Comment: The OP wants to return only the name of the member with the lowest result. So you need to wrap this query within an outer query and filter by `result = min_result`.

Comment: @James B: Okay, this is another task. As mathguy says: wrap this with an outer query. You could also use `rank` (or `dense_rank`) instead of `min over`. The easiest way, however, would be to simply add `FETCH FIRST 1 ROW WITH TIES`, but this is only available as of Oracle 12c.